# Activate the References View in VSCode 1.30

Tags: visual-studio-code

The November 2018 release of Visual Studio Code advertises the new References View:

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_30#_references-view

The View is "hidden at startup". How can I activate it? Right-click on the Activity Bar does not show the option. Also, right-clicking any symbol does not show "Find All References".

Is this feature limited to a set of languages? I tried it with C and Python projects.

```
Version: 1.30.0
Commit: c6e592b2b5770e40a98cb9c2715a8ef89aec3d74
Date: 2018-12-11T22:29:11.253Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Windows_NT x64 6.1.7601
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the below steps (done for Javascript):

**Version check**

[image]

**1) Not yet used**

[image]

**2) First use**

[image]

**3) After first use**

[image]

Comment: With a temporary .js file I can activate the option and use it in this session. But the activity button disappears next time I start VSCode, although "find all references" seems to work with python.